# mysql_num_rows equivalent for JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

Can you do a similar test when returning JSON with PHP like mysql_num_rows?

Therefore i can do an IF statement and echo a different piece of text for when there's no JSON available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = json_decode("some json");
echo count($data);
```

Comment: how about if your json has 1 extra level... would you do `count($data[0])` for ex?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the context is but you can do

```
$array = json_decode($json_string);
$num = count($array);
```

That's if the json_string is an array.